# How to load a url in a html div ? that url may be public domain or local web application url using html,javascript

Tags: javascript, html, url

How to load a url in a html div ? that url may be public domain or local web application url using html,javascript.

example urls:
http://www.gmail.com
htt://my ip with port/ProjectName/index.html

thank you

Comment: Why not use an `iframe` instead? They are meant to be used for this very purpose.

Comment: iframe also not worked.it worked for some urls.

Comment: this iframe code lods some urls but not all                    <script src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.js" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
             $("#siteloader").html('<object data="http://localhost:8080/job/SFDC"/>');
            })
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="siteloader"></div>
    </body>

Answer (score 2):

you can load the content from same domain and protocol only using ajax

you can make cross domain ajax request too but in that case the server must send `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header

In case of gmail you cannot do this but if you are working with your own website / domain you can set header

**PHP** can be used for this

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

However there are other methods too which can be used to set headers, one of them is using **.htaccess** in case of apache server

here is example of setting header using .htaccess

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"
</ifModule>
```

Comment: you can't load data via ajax from other domain & protocol without proper `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, however you can always use iframe anywhere as you want

Comment: even i frame also not loding the url.it shows Refused to display 'https://www.google.co.in/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.  for src=https://www.google.co.in

Comment: because google retruns `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN` header and this header forbades browser to load page under domain than google, you can try some other URL, simply you can do this google